# Equivalent unix command translate to powershell

Tags: powershell

Can you help to translate unix command powershell.

```
cat filename |sed 's/ *$//' >fileout
```

Thanks

Comment: "can you help" sounds more like "do it for me". Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am new to powershell, i don't know how to convert sed commands in powershell. I need to run that in windows. Can you help on that.

Comment: Being new isn't an excuse to be lazy. Put some effort in and try something. [Here's what 5 seconds of googling found me](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2007/07/09/grep-and-sed-with-powershell.aspx). Should get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Anyway, your question isn´t a question... what is a "unix command powershell" :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I got it right. I guess it was regex for trimming the end of the lines.

```
(Get-content filename) | % { $_ -replace ' *$', '' } | Set-content filename
```

Thanks to aliases, we could make it even more familiar for you like this:

```
(cat filename) | % { $_ -replace ' *$', '' } > filename
```

You could also do it like this:

```
(Get-content filename) | % { $_.TrimEnd() } | Set-content filename
```

Comment: I like the TrimEnd() approach but the parens around (Get-Content Filename) above is unnecessary.

Comment: I would normally agree, but the sample reads and saves using the same file(`filename`), so I had to fully read the file before processing. As I'm reading the question again, I see that he's using different filenames, in which case the parens is unnecessary as you've said. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. it works. I have a question. I transferred the file to UNIx and ran cat filename|sed "s/ *$//" >filename.out . I checked the outputs from both powershell and unix, the bytes size are different, Why ?. I removed ^M chars. I did unix diff, i do see differences. Any thoughts ?.

Comment: Unix is bigger? I'd take a guess at encoding. Powershell uses ASCII encoding by default which is 7bit, while I'm guessing Unix uses some sort of unicode 8bit.